# PHP my if function for isset gives false value after pressing submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a problem for a sign up page of my website which was working before but nothing changed and now it started to give error by giving the false value in my 'if(isset($_POST['signup']))' function after i press the submit button that has name of "signup". below is all of my code for my signing up proccess so the error should be there somewhere but couldn't find it.

signup.php :

```
<?php include 'includes/session.php'; ?>
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('location: cart_view.php');
  }

 

?>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<body class="hold-transition register-page" style="background-image:url('images/log-bg.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: center; background-size: cover;">
<div class="register-box">
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
        echo "
          <div class='callout callout-danger text-center'>
            <p>".$_SESSION['error']."</p> 
          </div>
        ";
        unset($_SESSION['error']);
      }

      if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
        echo "
          <div class='callout callout-success text-center'>
            <p>".$_SESSION['success']."</p> 
          </div>
        ";
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
      }
    ?>
    <div class="register-box-body" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>

        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['firstname'])) ? $_SESSION['firstname'] : '' ?>" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) ? $_SESSION['lastname'] : '' ?>"  required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['email'])) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '' ?>" required>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repassword" placeholder="Retype password" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          
          <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button style="background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39); color:white; width:100px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-flat" name="signup"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      <br>
      <a style="color: rgb(39, 39, 39);" href="login.php">I already have a membership</a><br>
      <a style="color: rgb(39, 39, 39);" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
    
<?php include 'includes/scripts.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

register.php :

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    include 'includes/session.php';

    if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $repassword = $_POST['repassword'];
        $contact = $_POST['contact'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];

        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['contact'] = $contact;
        $_SESSION['address'] = $address;
        

        

        if($password != $repassword){
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'Passwords did not match';
            header('location: signup.php');
        }
        else{
            $conn = $pdo->open();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM users WHERE email=:email");
            $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email]);
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if($row['numrows'] > 0){
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Email already taken';
                header('location: signup.php');
            }
            else{
                $now = date('Y-m-d');
                $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                //generate code
                $set='123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $code=substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 12);

                try{
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, activate_code, created_on, contact_info, address) VALUES (:email, :password, :firstname, :lastname, :code, :now, :contact, :address)");
                    $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password, 'firstname'=>$firstname, 'lastname'=>$lastname, 'code'=>$code, 'now'=>$now, 'contact'=>$contact, 'address'=>$address]);
                    $userid = $conn->lastInsertId();

                    $message = "
                        <h2>Thank you for Choosing .</h2>
                        <p>Your Account Details:</p>
                        <p>Email: ".$email."</p>
                        <p>Password: ".$_POST['password']."</p>
                        <p>Please click the link below to activate your account.</p>
                        <a href='http://localhost/activate.php?code=".$code."&user=".$userid."'>Activate Account</a>
                    ";

                    //Load phpmailer
                    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
                    try {
                        //Server settings
                        $mail->isSMTP();                                     
                        $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:25';                      
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
                        $mail->Username = 'mymail';     
                        $mail->Password = 'pass';                    
                        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                            'ssl' => array(
                            'verify_peer' => false,
                            'verify_peer_name' => false,
                            'allow_self_signed' => true
                            )
                        );                         
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           
                        $mail->Port = 25;                                   

                        $mail->setFrom('mymail');
                        
                        //Recipients
                        $mail->addAddress($email);              
                        $mail->addReplyTo('mymail');
                       
                        //Content
                        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                        $mail->Subject = 'Sign Up';
                        $mail->Body    = $message;

                        $mail->send();

                        unset($_SESSION['firstname']);
                        unset($_SESSION['lastname']);
                        unset($_SESSION['email']);

                        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Account created. Check your email to activate.';
                        header('location: signup.php');

                    } 
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
                        header('location: signup.php');
                    }


                }
                catch(PDOException $e){
                    $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                    header('location: register.php');
                }

                $pdo->close();

            }

        }

    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Fill up signup form first';
        header('location: signup.php');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Something must have changed, since there is no reason for a script to change its behaviour if the input and the environment are still the same. I did not notice anything wrong at a glance. Have you tried dumping the `$_POST` variable to check the contents?

Comment: i mean the only change that i remember is my o.s but i doubt it's that,

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry i dont know if it is because my main language is different or i just dont know what dumping means

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<input type="hidden" name="signup" value="1"/>` instead of adding the name to a button? First time i see giving the button a name.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal just tried that too, nothing changes still gives the else value from my if

Comment: Where did you add the hidden input? Have you removed the name from the button? Are you sure you didnt just press F5 to resent the data from browser but made sure to load the page of `signup.php` with the new content and then press the button again to send the form?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal added it one line before the button but didnt work, i dont think that is the problem or it would not have worked before at all

Comment: Just to clarify are all my other questions answered with yes?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal yes, the new content was loaded and i pressed on the button again to send the form

Comment: Are you sure the post parameter gets passed by? Have you tried as el_vanja suggested to dump the $_POST variable? as an example `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '<pre>'; die();'`? Is the index 'signup' present in $_POST? Probably better you update your question with this output.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal where do you want me to add this, in register.php ?

Comment: at the top of register.php directly after `<?php `, you dont need to worry about your other code since `die();` stops further execution of the code.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal it showed me an array and everything looks ok;

Array
(
    [firstname] => Ta
    [lastname] => Ca
    [email] => email@emaail.com
    [password] => pass
    [repassword] => pass
    [contact] => 501
    [address] => samplead
    [signup] => signup
)

Comment: Are you sure the function returns false? Again write `echo '<pre>'; var_dump(isset($_POST['signup'])); echo '<pre>'; die();` at the top of register.php after `<?php `, if it dumps `true` then it will enter the if condition unless `include 'includes/session.php';` unsets this value. In any case you need to do more debugging. Go through every variable check its current value and check if it is your expected value.

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal ooh so i was wrong, it gave me true value but for a reason it does the function where it should be false

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a `value` attribute ...

```
<button style="background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39); color:white; width:100px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-flat" name="signup" value="xxx"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Sign Up</button>
```

... or check the post data with `array_key_exists();`

```
if (array_key_exists('signup', $_POST)){ ...
```

This happens because `isset()` also checks on null value:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-isset-and-array_key_exists-function-in-php/#:~:text=The%20isset()%20function%20is,in%20all%20other%20possible%20cases](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-isset-and-array_key_exists-function-in-php/#:%7E:text=The%20isset()%20function%20is,in%20all%20other%20possible%20cases).